# Interface builder no longer generate ARC compliant code for IBOutlets

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, iboutlet

I'm implementing my first iOS 5.1 application using XCode 4.3.2 and I'm experimenting a strange XCode interface builder behavior.

I created a ViewController with NIB file in the interface builder and when connecting any UI object to the ViewController .h in order to create the IBOutlet properties, the dialog windows to set the outlet properties doesn't show the Storage field.

To be clear, the interface builder show this dialog:

[image: Screenshot 1]

instead of this one:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Consequently, the code generated by the interface builder is like the following:

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelName;
```

while the code I'm expecting is:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelName;
```

This behavior starts to occurs from a couple of days and just for one project, so my suspicious is that I accidentally changed some project setting.

Any help to restore the XCode Interface Builder behaviour in order to generate ARC code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're both the same. And besides, it seems right to me... what's the problem here?

Comment: It looks right apart from `UILabel` rather than `UILabel*`.

Comment: @mattjgalloway you're right, I corrected the code

Comment: What am I missing? Both lines are identical.

Comment: Both of those lines are the same. > This behavior starts to occurs from a couple of days and just for one project, so my suspicious is that I accidentally changed some project setting. Run a diff against an earlier version, it will show you what has changed.

Comment: @Abizern sorry, my fault. I corrected the code and added two screenshots of the interface builder dialogs

Comment: sorry, my fault. I corrected the code and added two screenshots of the interface builder dialogs

Comment: Did you run a diff against an earlier version?

Comment: @Jim the problem is not about the code itself, but about the XCode interface builder behavior. I added in the question a couple of screenshots that hopefully explain the situation better than my words ( ...sorry for my bad English).

Comment: @Massimiliano, if you run a diff against an earlier version, it will determine the project setting that has changed to cause this.  If it previously worked correctly and now it does not, finding out what changed is the obvious solution to your problem, and you do this by running a diff against an earlier version.

Comment: @Jim OK, now I understood your suggestion. Which are the files that contains the project settings against the which I have to run the diff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your target is 4.x right? In that case you can't use weak and so it uses unsafe_unretained. They're the same thing except unsafe_unretained does not automatically nil the pointer for you but that doesn't particularly matter for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The app target is **5.x** . This is why I suspect some misconfiguration within the project.

Comment: Are you sure? I am talking about the deployment target, not the SDK you are using.

Comment: Yes, iOS deployment target is set to 5.0 both on project and target setting.

Comment: Hmm odd then. But really, does it matter to you anyway?

Comment: I tried to generate the IBOutlet and then I changed the property declaration in the ARC way and it seems to work. So I can survive, but usually I would like to understand what happen! ;-) This time this strange XCode behavior do not have serious impacts on my work, but what can happen tomorrow?

Comment: But what I mean is, unsafe_unretained and weak are not that semantically different. I won't go into full depth as you can read about it. So why does it matter?

Comment: I understand your position and I don't want you waste your time. Now I see this XCode malfunction doesn't impact seriously on my work so I can go on over. It remains the fact that I don't feel to have the full control on the development environment (I'm pretty new to iOS development and XCOde), but probably this is not the right place to discuss about it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem, it's not a waste of time :-). Things do change between Xcode versions which may have been what's happened here. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably switched off the `ARC` on your project/target settings.
Switch to `Yes` and you'll get back the `Storage` field.

[image]

Comment: In which project setting section is the ARC parameter?

Comment: @Massimiliano it's in 'Build Settings' tab.

Comment: I checked both project and target settings and I found ARC entries on "Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 - Language" and "Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 - Warning" sections. In these sections ARC is set on YES. Am I missing any other ARC parameter?

Comment: It's "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" setting in the "compiler" section in the "build settings" of the "target". If that's set to "Yes" and you're still not seeing the "Storage" setting, I'd suggest (a) perform a "clean" from the "product" menu; and (b) you go to your "build settings" again and click on "validate settings". Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but the behavior is still the same. As you can see on the other answer comments, this is not an issue that seriously impact on my work. It's just to understand what happened in order to acquire more control on the development environment. Thank so much anyway.

Comment: @Massimiliano It may not really impact your work but I totally agree with you that is a matter of feeling like you're in control of your IDE. Did you try to delete 'derived data' folder and clean/rebuild your project?

Comment: @Alladinian Yes, I did but nothing changed. At this point open an issue against Apple Support could be an option. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Massimiliano The fact that this happens only for a specific project indicates indeed that the culprit must be a project-specific setting, but yes Apple support would be able to shed some light on it.